# Access Violation occurs when using std::promise and std::future

Tags: c++, multithreading, future, access-violation

In my code, I dispatch tasks to my thread pool with a construct that more-or-less looks like this:

```
working_data get_data(my_thread_pool & thread_pool) {
    size_t thread_pool_size = thread_pool.size();
    std::vector<working_data> data(thread_pool_size);
    std::vector<std::promise<void>> promises(thread_pool_size);
    
    std::mutex data_0_mutex;
    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < thread_pool_size; i++) {
        thread_pool.post_task([&, i] {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(data_0_mutex, std::defer_lock);
            if(i == 0) 
                lock.lock();
            data[i].add_data(process_data());
            if(i != 0) {
                lock.lock();
                data[0].merge_from(data[i]);
            }
            promises[i].set_value();
        });
    }
    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < thread_pool_size; i++) {
        promises[i].get_future().wait();
    }
    
    return std::move(data[0]);
}
```

While this doesn't happen *every time* I execute this code, many times when executing it, this code causes an access violation.

Conversely, the following code never causes access violations, but *I'd rather not use it because I don't like the use of the polling loop at the end*:

```
working_data get_data(my_thread_pool & thread_pool) {
    size_t thread_pool_size = thread_pool.size();
    std::vector<working_data> data(thread_pool_size);
    std::vector<std::atomic_bool> flags(thread_pool_size);
    
    std::mutex data_0_mutex;
    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < thread_pool_size; i++) {
        thread_pool.post_task([&, i] {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(data_0_mutex, std::defer_lock);
            if(i == 0) 
                lock.lock();
            data[i].add_data(process_data());
            if(i != 0) {
                lock.lock();
                data[0].merge_from(data[i]);
            }
            flags[i].store(true, std::relaxed_memory_order);
        });
    }
    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < thread_pool_size; i++) {
        while(!flags[i].load(std::relaxed_memory_order))
            std::this_thread::yield();
    }
    
    return std::move(data[0]);
}
```

Note that the main difference is that I'm using `std::atomic_bool` instead of `std::promise` and `std::future`.

It's quite possible that the error is being caused somewhere else in my [2000+ lines of] code, but I'd like to know if there's an obvious mistake solely in the code I'm presenting here.

## EDIT:

One other thing I've observed: I cannot recreate the bug if I turn optimizations off. This bug only occurs when optimizations are turned on.

## DOUBLE EDIT COMBO:

The call stack for *where* the access violation occurs is unreadable:

[image: Call Stack]

Comment: Where is the access violation?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I've posted the call stack. It doesn't help much, unfortunately.

Comment: Is `data[0].merge_from` safe to call if `data[0].add_data` hasn't been called yet?

Comment: Try unlocking the lock before setting the value in the promise.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm You can think of `merge_from` as being an alias for `std::vector`'s `insert` function. What it actually does is a bit more complicated, but it functions perfectly fine if there's no data in the object to start with.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Unlocking the lock before calling `promises[i].set_value();` totally worked! You can submit it as an answer and I'll accept it, but I'd love to know what difference that makes, as it makes no sense to me that the ordering there matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is one of timing.

When the last thread sets its promise's value, this allows the loop in the main thread to finish, which in turn causes the `data_0_mutex` object to be destroyed.  That last thread can still be running, and when the destructor for `lock` is called, the mutex it references has been (or is being) destroyed.

This isn't as likely a problem in your "polling" version, as the main thread has to wait for the OS to resume it, but it could still happen.

The solution is to free the lock before setting the promise, by calling

```
lock.unlock();
```

before `promise[i].set_value();`.